# Performance issue with where condition on view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view and try to access view data by applying where filter

When i directly filtered using name i am getting results with in a second. But when declare a variable and passing that variable to where condition i am getting result in 20sec.. Please let me know why that much difference coming when using variable in where condition

```
select  count(1) from vw_Student where studentName='raja'; (result in 1sec)

declare @name char(4);
set @name='raja'
select  count(1) from vw_Student where studentName=@name;(result in 20sec)
```

Comment: Do they have the same Execution Plan? ( how to check Execution Plan: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-query-execution-plan-beginners-types-options/ )

Comment: It's neither the `where` condition nor the view. The important information is the execution plan, the table definition, the view statement and the indexes, none of which appear in this question.

Comment: The variable is a fixed width value, `char(4)` instead of the more common `varchar(..)`. This means that the data has to be filtered using fixed-length semantics - shorter values *have* to be padded to the full length first. This means that any indexes created on `studentName` are useless because they are based on the full text, not the padded/truncated values. Change the variable type to `varchar(4)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you are wrong, varchar has higher precedence than char so of course shorter values won't be padded. The variable will be implicitly converted to varchar, not vice versa.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin without *any* information we can only guess. A missed index can easily produce a delay. For that to happen it means the index was unsuitable - either because the underlying field has the wrong type, or *a conversion is required* before using the index. That's the case with collation mismatches, functions on fields and in this case, comparing fixed width with variable length strings.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, *will return the 'a' (no space) and 'a ' (two trailing spaces)* - this is about string comparison in T-SQL, not about type convertion. Values with any count of trailing spaces will be returned because the first step on the string comparison is to make strings be the same length

Comment: @DenisRubashkin again `without any information` and `only difference`. Somehow, an index isn't used. The need for a conversion is a possible explanation. We can only guess or try to come up with a scenario that produces the same result, only to find out that the query is *very* different from what we thought. Frankly, I don't have the time to come up and test imaginary scenarios.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I commented because that comment was marked as useful but it is incorrect. As for the question, I'm pretty sure due to using density vector instead of histogram the optimizer estimates incorrectly count of rows from some table and perform clustered index (or table) scan to avoid key lookups.